# PHP mailer change sender address using yahoo.com

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to change the sender address of the mail. Firstly I tried by gmail, then I let to know that by gmail its not possible now I am trying using Yahoo, and I got following error:-

SMTP ERROR: MAIL FROM command failed: 553 From address not verified.

Getting blank here I dont understand what do I do? Any help will be appreciated. following is my code:-

```
  <?php 
//date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$body = 'This is the message';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; 
//$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

$mail->Username   = 'myyahooid@yahoo.com';
$mail->Password   = 'xyz';
$name='Test Name';
$mail->Sender='thishavetoset@domain.com';
//$mail->From = 'sender@senderdomain.com';
//$mail->FromName = 'Sender Name';
$mail->SetFrom('thishavetoset@domain.com', $name, TRUE);

$mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@mycomp.com','no-reply');
$mail->Subject    = 'subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress('myyahooid@yahoo.com', 'title1');
//$mail->AddAddress('abc2@yahoo.com', 'title2'); /* ... */
$fileName='../rough/test.pdf';
$mail->AddAttachment($fileName);
//$mail->send();
 if(!$mail->Send())
   {
  echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
  }

 echo "Message has been sent";
  ?>
```

Let me know another solution to set the sender name also if you think, it can't be done this way. Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The sender email you using should be real email id and as your using Yahoo mail i think then it must registered in yahoo 
There are two reasons smtp trows such error are.

first is You are attempting to send email to a domain that is not recognized by this server
second is You are attempting to relay email through this server and have not authenticated

Check if $mail->Sender='thishavetoset@domain.com'; email is set for your domain name your using.

So try to use email which user email password your using.
$mail->Username   = 'myyahooid@yahoo.com';

Comment: Yes I also read same. So is there any way to change the sender address? If I use another domain?

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail you can add that email id as external address from accounts and import tab >> add another email address, You will need details of smtp from the Admin of hosting/domain and add the email id.

once you add the external email address you can use that email id as sender from gmail smtp.